# Работа ссылки и указателя на указатель

Tags: c++

Всем добрый день. В методичке был такой кусок кода:

```
void delete_stack(stack** p) {
stack* time;
while (*p != NULL) {
    time = *p;
    *p = (*p)->next;
    delete time;
}}
```

И вызов данной функции:

```
delete_stack(&begin);
```

Где ***begin-указатель на структуру** stack* (однонаправленный список).
Код рабочий, но хотелось бы глубже разобраться, почему при вызове функции используется адрес, а сама функция принимает указатель на указатель, и как ещё это можно использовать

Comment: При вызове используется не ссылка, а адрес. Для того, чтобы при выходе из функции эта переменная приняла значение `NULL`. Кстати, в С++ лучше использовать `nullptr`...

Comment: Неужели указатель на указатель и последующие жонглирования с ними нужны лишь для возвращения **NULL**?

Comment: Да, преподаватель говорил что указатель на указатель не нужен, и этого можно избежать. Однако хотелось бы точно узнать, как работает указатель на указатель и передача адреса, и где это можно использовать

Comment: Вот тут и использовано — для того, чтоб после `delete_stack(&begin);` значение `begin` было `NULL`.

Comment: в каких случаях вы вообще указатели используете?   Чтобы указывать на разные объекты выполняя смещение или присваивание или сделать нулевым, когда ни на что  не нужно указывать... Для указателя на указатель объектом является указатель(вся разница)

Comment: @Harry,  это да, но ведь  сделать его нулевым можно и после вызова функции и в  первых строках тела функции и можно передать ссылку на указатель.. Нет?...

Comment: ну указатель нужен для обнуления переменной **begin**. А код `*p = (*p)->next;` при каждом проходе цикла *обновляет* её. Постоянное обновление переменной по адресу это плохая практика по скорости выполнения, обычно вводят дополнительную локальную переменную указателя и потом уже в конце удалённо это указатель обнуляют.

Comment: Такой прием обычно используется, если нужно исключать элементы в односвязном списке. Т.е. вы адресуете указатель на следующий элемент. Смотрите через этот указатель на содержимое следующего элемента и если он подлежит выбрасыванию из списка, то просто записывает в поле связи текущего содержимое указателя на следующий из следующего элемента. Как бы прыгаете через один. В этом случае переключаться на следующий уже не надо, а если решили оставить следующий элемент в списке, то переходите на него (адресуете уже его указатель на следующий)